# Error [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, testng

**Actual Error**:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/Mahnoor%20Luqman/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.4.9/groovy-2.4.9.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**I am using Eclipse Photon latest version with java 10.0.2 version.**

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?
Help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

[Screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVsPl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there are Java 9 (and 10, ...) [compatibility issues for Groovy](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2995). Maybe you could try to upgrade to the latest version of Groovy.

Comment: But i am not using groovy. Is it hidden with other libraries?

Comment: Yes, it's likely a dependency of another lib. I would start by upgrading all the dependencies to the latest version, and see if the problem still occurs.